# When I am hitting url with /static then I am getting nginx 403 forbidden error

Tags: nginx

When I am hitting url https://portal-dev7.domain.com/static on browser then it's showing nginx 403 error. and when I am hitting url https://portal-dev7.domain.com/abc like without /static then it's loading sign in page or home page or dashboard page.

Why this error is coming with /static?. My application is hosted on AKS cluster.

Comment: your app it self blocking it 403 error for forbidden access so please check the route or any other auth option.

Comment: I have applied   this annotation  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /  in our ingress controller yaml file and also restarted controller. But still m getting 403 error with /static

Comment: Share you Config yaml file ingress that helpful for others to get idea.